# Finding Rank K approximation of an Image

Tags: python, pandas, numpy, jupyter-notebook

I am writing a function that finds the rank approximation of an image. I managed to get it work when K is equal to 1 & 2, but I can't find figure out a way to make a generalized function. Also, i successfully managed to make the U/Vh/s variables by calling linalg.svd().

For rank 2 I did something like this to combine the images and those worked successfully to sum up the SVD's

```
rank1TotalOne = np.dstack((rank1Redone, rank1Greenone, rank1Blueone))
rank1TotalTwo = np.dstack((rank1Redtwo, rank1Greentwo, rank1Bluetwo))

plt.imshow((rank1TotalOne + rank1TotalTwo).astype(int))
```

Now I tried to generalize it into something like this but my images are not turning showing up correctly.

```
k = 10
rankTotal = 0
j = 0
for i in range(0, k):
    while(j < k):
        columnVect = UR[:, j].reshape(300,1)
        rowVect = VhR.T[:,j].reshape(1, 200)
        rank1Red = sR[j] * columnVect * rowVect

        columnVect = UG[:, j].reshape(300,1)
        rowVect = VhG.T[:,j].reshape(1,200)
        rank1Green = sG[j] * columnVect * rowVect

        columnVect = UB[:, j].reshape(300,1)
        rowVect = VhB.T[:,j].reshape(1,200)
        rank1Blue = sB[j] * columnVect * rowVect

        rank1Total = rank1Total + np.dstack((rank1Red, rank1Green, rank1Blue))
        rank1Total = rank1Total.astype(int)
        j = j + 1

plt.imshow(rank1Total)
plt.show()
```

Comment: Check the how its done in this notebook https://github.com/AlexanderNixon/DataScience-Notes/blob/master/Numerical_Linear_Algebra/SVD/SVD-applications.ipynb

Answer (score 0):

I am really dum i just noticed with my code I have a rank1Total and rankTotal variable.

```
rankTotal = rankTotal + np.dstack((rank1Red, rank1Green, rank1Blue))
rankTotal = rankTotal.astype(int)
j = j + 1

plt.imshow(rankTotal)
plt.show()
```

I just needed to go from rank1Total to rankTotal, this is because rankTotal what i wanted everything to be saved to.